# git stash apply no vuelve a lo que tenia por un directorio /.idea

Tags: git, phpstorm

en mi proyecto hice un git stash, para bajar unas cosas, ahora no puedo voerl a git stash apply porque me dice que  tengo untracked files

```
.idea/php.xml
```

ese en concreto, sin sentido, no puedo volver al estado que tneia antes

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .idea/php.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener un contexto completo de lo que sucedió cuando creaste el stash, probablemente lo que ocurrió es que ese archivo `.idea/php.xml` fue *agregado* al índice como archivo nuevo (cosa que no debería suceder en general porque no es buena idea guardar metadata del IDE, pero ese es otro asunto) y entonces creaste el stash. Cuando eso sucedió, por defecto, git stash debió eliminar el archivo del árbol de trabajo (aunque queda como parte de los que se guarda en el stash). El archivo fue creado de nuevo y entonces, ahora que estás pidiéndole a git que aplique el stash, te está diciendo que el archivo va a ser sobreescrito.